# Why Does CruiseControl.net Build Still Succeed When Exec Task Fails?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have this task in publishers after xmllogger:

```
      <exec>
    <executable>CheckForWarnings.cmd</executable>
    <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>
    <baseDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>all</buildArgs>
  </exec>
```

I've verified that this task is returning a non-0 exit code via the ccnet service logs:

2013-01-29 23:21:20,571 [Encompass.2013R1:INFO] Integration complete: Failure - 1/29/2013 11:21:20 PM

So why is the build still green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks put inside the `publisher` section will not change the build result, **as they are part of the report** (publisher) and not the build (tasks).

> The publishers section is run after the build completes (whether it
>   passes or fails). This is where you aggregate and publish the build
>   results.

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Tasks_and_Publishers

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the exec task in the tasks section, not the publish section, if you want it to fail the build.